Optional stopping theorem setup when $\mathbb{E}(\tau) <\infty$
Suppose $S_n = \sum_{i = 1}^{n}X_i$ is a real zero-mean random walk with i.i.d. bounded symmetric increments $\{X_i\}_{i\in\mathbb{N}}$ such that $|X|\leq 1$ and $\mathbb{E}(X^2) = \frac{1}{3}$.
Let $T = \inf\{n\in\mathbb{N}:|S_n|\in A\}$ be a stopping time for the martingale $S_n$ (where $A\subseteq\mathbb{R}^{+}$) and suppose that $\mathbb{E}(T) < \infty$. In this case we can apply the "Optional stopping theorem" because the expectation of the stopping time is finite and $S_n$ has bounded increments.
Let $M_n = S_n^2-\frac{n}{3}$ the "quadratic" martingale associated to the random walk $S_n$.
We can think the previous stopping time $T$ as a stopping time for this new martingale, since $|S_n| \in A \Longleftrightarrow M_n \in B$, where $B\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ is properly scaled and translated (for example, $|S_n| > \sqrt{n} \Longleftrightarrow S_n^2 > n \Longleftrightarrow M_n > \frac{2n}{3}$). We know that $\mathbb{E}(T) < \infty$ from before, but I think that $M_n$ has no longer bounded increments (?!)
$$
|M_{n+1}-M_n| = \Bigl|S_{n+1}^2-S_n^2-\frac{1}{3}\Bigr| = \Bigl|X_{n+1}^2+2X_{n+1}S_n-\frac{1}{3}\Bigr|
$$
My question is if it is possible to apply the "Optional stopping theorem" to the stopping time $T$ associated to the martingale $M_n$ anyway.
Thank you for any help.
Edit 1

Durret problem 4.8.3 - Random walk and optional sampling theorem application

Maybe that post could be helpful.

Generally, $(M_n){n\ge0}$ will not be uniformly integrable so the optional stopping theorem does not apply directly. However, depending on what you want to prove, it is often enough to apply it to $(M{n \wedge k})$ for arbitrary $k$, and let $k\to\infty$ at a later step.

Because $\tau\wedge k$ is trivially bounded by $k$.. correct? :D (You meant $M_{\tau\wedge k}$ when you wrote $M_{n\wedge k}$ or..?)

Whatever. You can apply the OST to $(M_{\tau\wedge n}){n\ge0}$ at the stopping time $k$, or to $(M{n\wedge k}){n\ge0}$ at the stopping time $\tau$, or to $(M_n){n\ge0}$ at the stopping time $\tau\wedge k$…

Okay, I think I understand! Thank you very much @nejimban

Suggestions:
1. The stopped process $K_n:= M_{T\wedge n}$ is a martingale. Therefore $\Bbb E[K_n]=\Bbb E[K_0] =0$ for each $n$.
2. By 1, $\Bbb E[S_{T\wedge n}^2] ={1\over 3}\Bbb E[T\wedge n]\le{1\over 3}\Bbb E[T]<\infty$, for each $n$.
3. Let $n\to\infty$ in 2. Notice that the sequence $\{S^2_{T\wedge n}\}$  is uniformly integrable (because $\{S_{T\wedge n}\}$ is an $L^2$-bounded martingale—see If ($M_t$) is a L2-bounded martingale then $M_t^2$ is uniformly integrable.) and converges a.s. to $S^2_T$.

Thank you! Yes, I did a very similar argument to solve my problem :D
